# Построение сектора в полярной системе координат основываясь на массиве точек

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

Нужно решить такую проблему. У нас есть полярная система координат и массив точек, нужно объединить эти точки в сектор и отобразить его. Все просто, берем минимальное и максимальное значения и проводим между ними сектор. Но вот в чем проблема, он никогда не пройдет через ноль. Сектор будет либо от нуля, либо до нуля. Соответственно такой сектор не правильный(не гибкий).

Нужен алгоритм построения сектора.
[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал примерно такой алгоритм. Углы в градусах. Код схематичный.

```
list.sort();
int size = list.size();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
      list.add(list[i] + 360);
int bestDeg= list[size-1] - list[0];
int left   = list[0];
int reigth = list[size-1];
for (int i=1; i<size;i++)
    if (bestDeg > list[size-1+i] - list[i]){
        bestDeg = list[size-1+i] - list[i];
        left   =  list[i];
        reigth =  list[size-1+i];
    }
```